# Router.navigate in dom event listener

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 8

Task sounds like this: user opens application in two tabs. User is signed in. And if user signs out in the first tab, then second tab should redirect user to `/login`.

I am using localstorage to store user's data and `storage` dom event which triggers when localstorage changes.

Here is my code:

```
    private _redirectIfUserLoggedOut(): void {
      window.addEventListener('storage', this._onStorageListener);
    }

    private _onStorageListener = () => {
      const currentUser = localStorage.getItem('__session_token');

      if (!currentUser) {
        this._router.navigate(['/login']) // this call doesn't work
      }
    }
```

The problem is: this._router.navigate doesn't work. Just nothing happens. But when I change `this._router.navigate` to `window.location.href = '/login'` redirection works.

`this` and `this._router` are **not undefined**

No errors or warnings in a console.

What is wrong with above code?

Comment: can you show the injection of the _router inside the component?

Comment: this code is in the service. constructor(private _router: Router)

Comment: the problem is your this is not working inside regular functions, use arrow functions or assign this to some another variable and then use that variable. It will work

Comment: _onStorageListener  is arrow function, look at the code more carefully please

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the event is triggered, the callback is executed from a different context i.e. from the window. So *this* in that case would refer to window, and there you don't have the router injected.

You could try to bind your service *this* to the event listener using: 
`window.addEventListener('storage', this._onStorageListener.bind(this));`

Comment: hm, no. It is not working. this is service. not window

Comment: do you have the RouterModule imported correctly in your AppModule ? (incl. forRoot() )